# typeid(complex<double>(0.0,1.0)) != typeid(1.0i)

Tags: c++, c++11, complex-numbers, user-defined-literals

Using `gcc 4.9` I found that types generated with type literal for complex numbers are not the same as when created by conventional means, i.e.:

```
typeid(complex<double>(0.0,1.0)) != typeid(1.0i)
```

1. Am I making a mistake here?
2. Is this a compiler bug or intended standard behavior?
3. If intended standard behavior: What is the rationale behind?

Adding the missing MCVE

```
#include <complex>
using std::complex;
using namespace std::literals::complex_literals;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <typeinfo>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (typeid(complex<double>(0.0, 1.0)) == typeid(1.0i))
        cout << "types are same as expected" << endl;
    else
        cout << "types are unexpectedly not the same" << endl;

    cout << 1.0i*1.0i << endl;
    cout << complex<double>(0.0, 1.0)*complex<double>(0.0, 1.0) << endl;
}
```

Compile instructions:

```
g++ -std=gnu++14 complex.cpp -o complex.exe
```

Output:

```
types are unexpectedly not the same
1
(-1,0)
```

Interestingly the literal does not even seem to be a proper imaginary number. (I am sure I am overlooking something...)

Comment: Any chance you can put that in a source list that actually compiles? I *think* you're using `std::complex<double>`, which is different than `_Complex`, the gnu-extension for imaginary constants, but without a MCVE its hard saying *what* you're actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for the update. yes, they're different types. Once is from the standard library, the other from a compiler extension.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce the problem in C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fbd46340ab9b14e) @WhozCraig The `i` is (also?) a literal suffix in C++14. In C++11 mode, gcc probably uses [this extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html)

Comment: @WhozCraig clang++ accepting the program in c++11 mode *with the gnu++11 extension* is probably a bug o.O

Comment: @dyp i had to double-take when I saw that myself. My mac OS X  clang 3.5 reference does the same, but at least gives a warning letting you know its an gnu extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The behaviour of the program depends on the *language standard mode* of gcc:

There is a [gcc extension for a **built-in** literal suffix `i`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html) that produces *C99 complex numbers*. Those are distinct **built-in** types like `_Complex double`, as opposed to the "user-defined" class (template specialization) `std::complex<double>` used in C++.

In C++14, C++ now has a *user-defined* literal suffix `i` for complex numbers. That is, a function `complex<double> operator"" i(long double)` within the `std::literals::complex_literals` inline namespace.

Those two literal suffixes are competing:

- In C++11 mode, only the built-in extension is possible, but it *is* an extension. Hence, gcc only allows it in `-std=gnu++11` mode and even warns you about it. Strangely enough, clang allows it even in `-std=c++11` mode.
- In *strict* C++14 mode (`-std=c++14` or `-std=c++1y`), the built-in extension must be disabled to remove ambiguity (as far as I can tell), hence both gcc and clang selecting the user-defined literal suffix.
- In the gnu-extension-C++14 mode `-std=gnu++14`, gcc chooses the built-in suffix (for backwards-compatibility?), whereas clang chooses the user-defined suffix. This looks strange, and I'd suggest looking for or filing bug reports here.

Depending on which literal suffix is chosen, you either get the built-in type `_Complex double` or some `std::complex<double>`.

Comment: Outstanding answer. I keep forgetting that user-defined literals came under the umbrella.