# std::complex initilalisation issue

Tags: c++, std, complextype

Consider the following code

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::complex<double> a = 1+1i;
    std::cout<<"a ="<<a<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile using Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) and the output that I get is

```
a =(1,0)
```

Can someone explain why the imaginary part is getting initialised with zero?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/Qa7698 did you forget to recompile at some point?

Comment: I was using Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1). Not g++!. I will edit the post

Comment: What happens when you add a using declaration `using namespace std::literals::complex_literals;`?

Comment: Repro: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QBES5VmGeMrfvZoT Probably some incompatibility between GCC extensions and C++ complex literals. I'd guess the GCC-extension is convertible to a double (the real part), so the `1+1i` is converted to double, then that result is used to initialize the std::complex.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28624861/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1 + 1i` is using a (GCC) extension which creates types similar/equivalent to C99's `_Complex int` type. That type is convertible to a real type like `int` or `double`. `std::complex` is not compatible to `_Complex`, it does not have any constructors to create a `std::complex` from a `_Complex` (*). But `std::complex<T>` does have a constructor that takes a `T`. This triggers the aforementioned conversion `_Complex` -> `T` -> `std::complex<T>`.

So the code in the OP is equivalent to:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double d = 1+1i;
    std::complex<double> a = d;
    std::cout<<"a ="<<a<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The imaginary part of `1 + 1i` is dropped in the conversion to `double`.

---

To prevent such surprises, try to compile with warnings and `-pedantic`. This example seems to be one of the few places where clang actually adds an additional warning with the `-pedantic` flag (for gcc, `-pedantic` changes the warning output in many contexts):

```
prog.cc:6:19: warning: imaginary constants are a GNU extension [-Wgnu-imaginary-constant]
    double d = 1+1i;
```

---

(*) IIRC, `std::complex` was introduced in C++98, while `_Complex` was introduced in C99.

Comment: GCC could add `std::complex::complex(_Complex)` for interoperability. This would be fairly safe as it does not appear to add new conversion sequences between C++ types.