# How to use user-defined literals for complex numbers?

Tags: c++, c++14, literals, complex-numbers, user-defined-literals

What am I doing wrong when I try to execute `std::pow(1.0i, 2)`? Is it my understanding of user-defined literal `operator""i`, or is it how I use the complex `pow`-overload?

The last line shows an error when compiling with g++-6.2 or g++-5:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using std::cout; using std::complex;
int main() {
    complex<double> z1 (0, 1);
    complex<double> z2 = std::pow(z1, 2);
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    complex<double> z3 = std::pow(1.0i, 2); // <<< error
}
```

The message is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘pow(__complex__ double, int)’
     complex<double> z3 = std::pow(1.0i, 2)
```

If I leave out the last line, all is fine.

Comment: C99 complex literals again :(   see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624861/typeidcomplexdouble0-0-1-0-typeid1-0i

Comment: Your code compiles for me `GCC 6.2.1`

Comment: @Galik Probably depends on the language standard flag. The GNU-variants will use C99-style complex types for the `i` literal suffix.

Comment: Indeed! thanks. `-std=c++1y` is right.